# AJAX/jQuery gives a mysterious integer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the latest jQuery. When I request some data from the server, I get a mysterious number ***5*** for no reasons at all. I checked my PHP code and console logged it and this is the result.

```
5<option value="" disabled selected>Choose your grade level</option>
                    <option value="9">Grade 9 - Red Lions</option>
```

There should no number 5 in that log at all.

AJAX Request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetch_levels.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {parent: $(this).val() },
    success: function(data)
    {
        var data = data;
        data.replace('5', '');
        $('#level-list').html(data);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    require '../assets/php/init.php';

    if ($_POST)
    {
        $schoolID   = Essentials::sanitize($_POST['parent']);

        $fetchSQL   = "SELECT `levelid`, `name` FROM `grade` WHERE schoolid = ?";
        $fetch      = $conn->prepare($fetchSQL);
        $fetch->execute([$schoolID]);
        $fetchRes   = $fetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!$fetchRes) {
            echo '
                <option value="" disabled selected>Unfortunately, there is no levels here.</option>
            ';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose your grade level</option>';
            foreach ($fetchRes as $level)
            {
                echo '
                    <option value="'.$level['levelid'].'">'.$level['name'].'</option>
                ';
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Tried Solutions:**

### I've tried adding `var data = data; data.replace('5', '')` and it still doesn't work.

**UPDATE**:
This is the *init.php*

```
<?php 
    # Configuration for the application
    $GLOBALS['config'] = [
        'registerAdmin' => true
    ];

    # Start the Session
    session_name('iLearn');
    session_start();

    # Include essentials files
    include 'language.php';

    # Autoregister Classes
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        require 'Classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    });

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=iLearn', "astroxoom", "-");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: add `exit` at the end of `php` file

Comment: Added but still doesn't work.

Comment: Look like a problem in `require '../assets/php/init.php';`

Comment: did u just try with simple php file `fetch_levels.php` having only `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>` ??

Comment: There is no problem with my init.php. I tried to only echo 'hello' and there is no more #5 and I also tried with my init.php and still no more #5

Comment: Could you post the `../assets/php/init.php` file?

Comment: @ChrisHappy Check it out.

Comment: Try remove `dataType: 'html',` (A random guess :) )

Comment: @ChrisHappy Still doesn't work :(

Comment: How about the `language.php` file. Could you post that & every other file related to your original file?

Comment: try to comment every echo `fetch_levels.php` then see what happens

Comment: @B.Desai I still get number 5.

Comment: That language.php is pretty long, [here is a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KSDdMaDF)

Comment: what is `Essentials::sanitize` ?

Comment: Function that gets the parameter $string, then `return strip_tags(trim($string));`

Comment: It cannot come from the file `fetch_levels.php` since you are removing all `5` from what it produces. It comes from somewhere else. You may now know where to search for it... But if you know where not to search for it, that's a start.

Comment: If you can to remove all JS and jQuery scripts... Just to see if it is coming from it. Just disable JavaScript in your browser would be a good fast test.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Just practicing the javascript make the jquery obsolete and this question is just nothing.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. Your opinion is strange. Do you dislike Bootstrap too? I was suggesting a debugging step, just to *know where to not search for nothing* everywhere. You do as you wish.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding, I think that jQuery is needed for Ajax and my code is using jQuery syntax; and no, I like Bootstrap and jQuery.